# OpenJTalkの辞書エントリのフォーマットがよくわかりません

Tags: 自然言語処理, mecab

日本語自然言語処理に興味を持つ中国の大学生です。最近はopenjtalkでg2pを行なっています。デフォルトのnaist-jdicに登録された単語は少ないので、ユーザー辞書を構造したいと考えています。でもこのnaist-jdicのエントリを見てみると、一般のMeCabスタイルのエントリとはちょっと違って、2項目の余計な情報が追加されています。

具体的に、一般のMeCab辞書のエントリは以下ように。

```
十三間,1353,1353,7678,名詞,固有名詞,地域,一般,*,*,十三間,ジュウサンゲン,ジューサンゲン
```

openjtalk辞書のエントリは以下のように

```
十三間,1353,1353,7678,名詞,固有名詞,地域,一般,*,*,十三間,ジュウサンゲン,ジューサンゲン,3/6,C1
```

この二つの余計な素性（3/6, C1）はアクセント句の韻律予測に関わると知っていますが、詳しい意味、使い方、構造方法などについてはやはりよく分からないです。

助けてください！

Comment: Open JTalk は音声合成ソフトウェアです。音声合成の部分は使わずに日本語の処理の部分だけを使っているということでしょうか？　もしかすると用語の混乱があるかもしれません。

Comment: コメントをいただき、ありがとうございます。確かに用語の混乱がありました。「openjtalkでg2pを行なっています」に編集されました。

Comment: 自分が知らなかっただけだとは思うのですが、g2p とは  grapheme-to-phoneme のことで合っていますか？

Comment: はい、その通りです。私は今openjtalkの日本語のテキスト前処理を行なってるだけですね :)

Comment: あっ、言い忘れたかもしれませんが、g2pだけを行うならmecabで十分だけど、私はテキストから韻律情報も抽出したいからopenjtalkを使っています。

Answer (score 5):

まず MeCab の辞書は、CSV として最初の 4 つのフィールドは必須ですが、それ以降はユーザー定義のフィールドとなっています。

> エントリは, 以下のような CSV で追加します.
>
> ```
> test,1223,1223,6058,foo,bar,baz
> ```
>
> 最初の4つは必須エントリで, それぞれ（中略）となっています.
> 5カラム目以降は, ユーザ定義の CSV フィールドです. 基本的に どんな内容でも CSV の許す限り追加することができます.

https://taku910.github.io/mecab/dic-detail.html

質問文の「一般の MeCab 辞書」はたくさんフィールドがありますが、おそらく mecab-ipadic のフォーマットです。

さて、Open JTalk が利用している辞書は、ヘルプの情報を信じるならば mecab-naist-jdic の Version 0.6.1-20090630 がベースです。ところが mecab-naist-jdic の辞書のフォーマットは、自分が確認した限りは mecab-ipadic のものと同じです。

このため、おそらく Open JTalk の辞書で追加されている 2 つのフィールドは Open JTalk 独自のものです。ソースコード（njd_set_accent_type など）を読む限り、追加フィールドはモーラ数やアクセントに関係するもののようです。

第三者による https://www.negi.moe/negitalk/openjtalk.html という調査によると追加されたフィールドはそれぞれ「<アクセント核>/<モーラ数>」「アクセントの結合処理のための情報」とのことです。

Comment: お答えいただき、ありがとうございます！情報助かります！第三者が記述された論文を見ていきたいと思います:)

Answer (score 3):

#### 最後の項目の「C1」などの記号

最後の項目の「C1」などの記号は、nekketsuuuさんの回答にある[「OpenJTalk の解析資料」](https://www.negi.moe/negitalk/openjtalk.html)にも触れられていますが、大まかに言うと「アクセント結合規則」を表現するもののようです。

多くの場所で「匂坂 芳典らによってまとめられた」という記述が有り、参考文献として下記2点が挙げられています。

- 『日本語単語連鎖のアクセント規則』
- 『テキストからの音声合成を目的とした日本語アクセント結合規則』

しかし、これらの論文をざっと見た限りでは、「C1」などの記号の付与に関しては説明されていません。後になって、別の場所で使用が始められた記号なのかも知れません。

関連する記号も含めると、下のような種類が有るようです。

- 付属語アクセント結合規則: F1 〜 F6
- 複合名詞アクセント結合規則: C1 〜 C5、C10
- 接頭辞アクセント結合規則: P1、P2、P4、P6、P13、P14
- アクセント修飾型規則: M1、M2、M4

参考（先行研究の紹介の中で、これらの記号の意味が説明されています）:

- [『条件付確率場に基づく日本語アクセント型予測モデルの改良と日本語教育システムへの応用』](https://repository.dl.itc.u-tokyo.ac.jp/records/3407)
- [『日本語音声合成のためのアクセント結合規則の改善とデータベースに基づく統計的アクセント処理』](https://repository.dl.itc.u-tokyo.ac.jp/records/1800)

Comment: コメントいただき、ありがとうございます！本当に助かります！